# Why do I get this error when I try to download this course from Udemy: Unable to download webpage, HTTP Error 403?

Tags: youtube-dl

I purchased a course from udemy and I am trying to download it with last version of youtube-dl but I get this error: **Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 403.** I tried `--rm-cache-dir` option but I did not work too. So what is the problem?


[image]

Answer (score 0):

403 means you are not allowed to do this operation. I assume this is an anti-piracy measure.

Comment: It was working before and I downloaded many courses.

Comment: Then maybe they changed their server configuration. The only other thing I could think of is that your credentials are invalid.

Comment: I am sure my credentials are correct and I logged in through the website.

Comment: Well, then, the part about anti-piracy measures seems more likely: they probably implemented some kind of blocking based on user agents, browser cookies, or whatever.

Answer (score -1):

#### TESTED AND WORKS ON A MAC OS

1. Install youtube-dl through `brew install youtube-dl`. If you used curl, you can remove it through `rm -rf /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl`.
2. If you face symlink permissions ERRORS, run `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` then `brew doctor` and fix each error according to the instructions.
3. `brew cleanup`
4. `brew link youtube-dl`
5. `cd .` (navigate to your favorable location that you wish to put your videos folder)
6. Login to udemy and get site cookies text file. I used [Get Cookies.txt](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/get-cookiestxt/).
7. `mkdir MyVideos`. (name it as you wish)
8. `youtube-dl --cookies udemy.com_cookies.txt -o '~/MyVideos/%(playlist)s/%(chapter_number)s - %(chapter)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s' https://www.udemy.com/<course-name>`
9. Done!